# Bluetooth Headset Toshiba Stack - Disable popup?

Tags: windows-7, bluetooth, headset

I have a USB Bluetooth radio and have used it over XP to connect my jawbone headset to my computer. I'm currently using the Toshiba Stack on Windows 7 Enterprise and it works fine.
I want to disable the popups that appear every time I connect my headset.

First I get this popup:

[image]

And then I automatically get this dialog box popping up:

[image]

It doesn't matter that I have already set it as the default communications device, *it always pops up*.

Does anyone know how to stop these popups from appearing automatically every time?